# Prove that all elements of finite group are different

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I can't prove with the following statement:

Let $(G,\Delta)$ a finite group. If $x\in G$, $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\geq 1$, $x^n=e$, we define $order$ $of$ $x$ to the minimun $n$ that satisfies that condition $x^n=e$ (we denote $o(x)$).

$S=\{e, x, x^2, ..., x^{n-1}\}$, $n=o(x)$.

1) Prove that all the elements of $S$ are different (that is $x^i\neq x^j$ if $i\neq j$, $0\leq i \leq n-1$, $0\leq j \leq n-1$.

2) Prove that $<x>=S$, and regarding Lagrange's Theorem prove that $o(x)/|G|$.

Answer (score 3):

Okay.  It is HORRIBLE to say "prove all elements of a set are different/distinct"  By definition all elements of *any* set are distinct.  And two, what your title is "all elements of a group are different" (which is true by definition) is completely different than your question that all $x^i$ for $0 \le i < n$ are distinct.

So what you want to ask is if $o(x) = n$ and then all the elements: $x^i$ for $1 \le k \le n$ distinct.

Suppose $x^i = x^j$ and $0 < i \le j\le n$.  Then $(x^{-1})^ix^i = (x^{-1})^ix^j$ so $e = x^{j-i}$  So if $0 < j-i < n$ this is a contradiction as $n$ is the smallest positive power where $x^k = 0$.  So $j - i = 0$ and $i = j$.

So if $i \ne j$ with $0 < i,j < n$ then $x^i \ne x^j$.

2) So since all the $x^i$ are distinct there are $n$ of them so $<x>$ will contain precisely those elements. i.e. if $g \in <x>$ then $g=x^{k = mn + i} = (x^n)^mg^i = e*x^i=x^i; 0\le i < n$ so in the list.  And obviously and $x^i\in <x>$ so $<x> = $ the list.

$<x>$ is a subgroup.  $<x>$ has $n$ elements.  so $|<x>|=n$ and by L.T. || = n = o(x)|$ divides $|G|$.

(Is that what $o(x)/|G|$ was supposed to mean? That $o(x)$ divides $|G|$?)

Answer (score 1):

Title: All elements of a finite group are different - this is always true by definition.

Text: What is $\Delta$?

1.) Suppose that $x^i=x^j$. We may assume that $i\ge j$. Then we can multiply by $x^{-j}$ and obtain $x^{i-j}=e$, a contradiction to $o(x)=n$.

2.) Follows from the definition of $\langle x\rangle $, with $o(x)=n$.